# Windows Phone 8 Geolocator cached location

Tags: c#, caching, windows-phone-8, geolocation

In Windows Phone app I get the geoposition like this:

```
Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
            maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

If I understand this correctly maximumAge means that the location can be cached and max 5 minutes old.

Can I use this "build in caching" so that when my app starts, I use GetGeopositionAsync(...) with maximumAge e.g. 2 (min), just to get fresh geopostitin with out actually using the geoposition.

Later in the app when I actually need the location, I call again GetGeopositionAsync(...) with maximumAge e.g. 10 (min). Now I should get the cached value (if it is still valid based on maximumAge)?

Does this make any sense? If this works as I expected, I do not need to build my own geoposition caching system.

Comment: why do you want to cache locations in the first place, are you worried about performance?

Comment: Yep, basically just to keep time what it takes to get user location low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. An MSDN blog post (http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/30/acquiring-a-single-geoposition-in-windows-phone-8.aspx) explains the caching using `MaximumAge` pretty good:

> `MaximumAge` defines a limit of how old a cached `Geoposition` can be,
>   from the time the operation starts, for it to be used by the app. By
>   default, the request will not return a cached Geoposition. If your app
>   can use cached positions for a brief period of time, this parameter
>   also can be seen as the validity time span. The app can simplify its
>   logic by letting the `Geolocator` handle the caching.
>
> For example, if the app sets `MaximumAge` to 5 minutes, the Geolocator
>   can satisfy that request with a `Geoposition` that is as old as 5
>   minutes from the time the request is started, as long as that position
>   meets the accuracy requirement specified by the app.
>
> Note that the `Geolocator` will always take the following sequential
>   steps to satisfy a request:
>
> 1. The request is started.
> 2. Identify whether a cached `Geoposition` satisfies the age and desired accuracy, and if so, immediately return it.
> 3. Trigger positioning technologies based on the desired accuracy.
> 4. Return a `Geoposition` when it meets the desired accuracy.
> 5. When the timeout is reached, if no position is available yet, error out. If there is a position available, given that the framework
>      follows a best-effort model, this `Geoposition` with a lower accuracy
>      than desired by the app can be returned at this time. The app can
>      decide whether the information is useful or to discard it.